# GPGPU - effective ping-pong technique?

Tags: glsl, webgl, gpgpu, render-to-texture

I'm trying to implement effective fluid solver on the GPU using WebGL and GLSL shader programming.

I've found interesting article:
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch38.html

See: ***38.3.2 Slab Operations***

I'm wondering if this technique of enforcing boundary conditions is possible with ping-pong rendering?
If I render only lines, what about an interior of the texture?
I've always assumed that the whole input texture must be copied to temporary texture (ofc boundary is updated during that process), as they are swapped after that operation.

This is interesting especially considering the fact, that ***Example 38-5. The Boundary Condition Fragment Program*** (visualization: https://i.stack.imgur.com/M4Hih.jpg)  shows scheme that IMHO requires ping-pong technique.

What do you think? Do I misunderstand something?

Generally I've found that texture write is extremely costly and that's why I would like to limit it somehow. Unfortunately, the ping-pong technique enforces a lot of texture writes.

Answer (score 1):

I've actually implemented the technique described in that chapter using [FrameBuffer objects](http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/latest/#5.14.6) as the render to texture method (but in desktop OpenGL since WebGL didn't exist at the time), so it's definitely possible. Unfortunately I don't believe I have the code any more, but if you tag any future questions you have with [webgl] I'll see if I can provide some help.

You will need to ping-pong several times per frame (the article mentions five steps, but I seem to recall the exact number depends on the quality of the simulation you want and on your exact boundary conditions). Using FBOs is quite a bit more efficient than it was when this was written (the author mentions using a GeForce FX 5950, which was a while ago), so I wouldn't worry about the overhead he mentions in the article. As long as you aren't bringing data back to the CPU, you shouldn't find too high a cost for switching between texture and the framebuffer.

You will have some leakage if your boundaries are only a pixel thick, but that may or may not be acceptable depending on how you render your results and the velocity of your fluid. Making the boundaries thicker may help, and there are papers that have been written since this one that explore different ways of confining the fluid within boundaries (I also recall a few on more efficient diffusion/pressure solvers that you might check out after you have this version working...you'll find some interesting follow ups if you search for [papers that cite the GPU gems article on google scholar](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=12343919752651377101&as_sdt=2005&sciodt=0,5&hl=en)).

Addendum: I'm not sure I entirely understand your question about boundaries. The key is that you must run a shader at each pixel of what you want to be a boundary, but it doesn't really matter how that pixel gets there, whether it's drawn with lines, points, or triangles (as long as its inputs are correct).

In the very general case (which might not apply if you only have a limited number of boundary primitives), you will likely have to draw a framebuffer-covering quad, since the interactions with the velocity and pressure fields are more complicated (any surrounding pixel could be another boundary pixel, instead of having simply defined edges). See section 38.5.4 (Arbitrary Boundaries) for some explanation of how to do it. If something isn't a boundary, you won't touch the vector field, and if it is, instead of hardcoding which directions you want to look in to sum vector values, you'll probably end up testing the surrounding pixels and only summing the ones that aren't boundaries so that you can enforce the boundary conditions.

Comment: My main concern is about specific application of boundary conditions described in this article. There are only 4 lines rendered instead of quad. I think it can be impossible during ping-pong rendering, as if I swap texture after rendering, it must be filled completely, not only on boundaries (so, render using quad, not lines). So, is it possible to render only 4 lines and use some trick or do I have to use quad?

Comment: see if the addition I made helps answer your questions.